# how to disable auto creation of new row while writing into Datagridview

Tags: c#

how to show one row of datagridview initially and how to disable new row creation while writing text into cells and create new row when enter key entered at last column of every row

Answer (score 1):

Its not mentioned either web or win application so, here is example for win app:

1- Creating new row first initially:

On form load or whenever you enter into specific section, add a row manually.
Like dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow("Name","Age",City"))

OR add it to datasource (datatable or list) and bind to DataGridview.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name");
  dt.Rows.Add(new DataRow(0," ");
  dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
  dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=false;
```

2- Handle cell click event to monitor, if its enter key and last cell then add another empty row into datasource.

```
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=true;
    dt.Rows.Add(new DataToRow(1,""));
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=true;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=false;
```

The code was written in notepad so not tested but gives an idea how to achieve the goal.

[This article explains DataGridView in details:](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748/0/page/4)

-thanks